# section of my code is being skipped (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-square

my program is supposed to check whether a matrix is a magic square. however it skips "adding the diagonals" and checking whether all the number (1-16) are in the table.

```
ROWS=4
COLUMNS=4

def main():

    tbl=[]
    numChecktbl=[]
    for i in range (ROWS):
        tbl.append([])
        for j in range (COLUMNS):
           userinput=int(input("Enter a value for location (%d,%d): " %(i,j)))
           tbl[i].append(userinput)
           numChecktbl.append(userinput)
    for i in range(ROWS):
        for j in range(COLUMNS):
           print("%3d" %tbl[i][j], end='') 
        print()
    if (totSumRowsColumns(ROWS,COLUMNS,tbl)and totSumDiagonals(ROWS,COLUMNS,tbl)
                     and numInMatrix(numChecktbl)):
        print("It is a magic square")
    else:
        print("It is not a magic square")

def totSumRowsColumns(ROWS,COLUMNS,tbl):
    for i in range (ROWS):
        totalrow=0
        totalColumn=0
        for j in range (COLUMNS):
            totalColumn+=tbl[j][i]
            totalrow=totalrow+tbl[i][j]
        if (totalrow != 34!=totalColumn):
            return False
        return True
def totSumDiagonals(ROWS,COLUMNS,tbl):    
    totDiag1=0  
    totDiag2=0
    for i in range (ROWS): 
        for j in range (COLUMNS):
            totDiag1=tbl[0][3]+tbl[1][2]+tbl[2][1]+tbl[3][0]
            if i==j:
               totDiag2+=tbl[i][j] 
    if (totDiag1!=totDiag2!=34):
        return False
    return True

def numInMatrix(numChecktbl):     
    for i in range(1,17):
        if i not in numChecktbl:
            return False
        return True
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your if statement contains multiple conditions that need to all be true, as soon as one is false it moves onto the else.

When your input is valid, all the functions and checks run. However, when your input is not a magic square, `totSumRowsColumns` returns false and the checks are stopped.

Comment: i ran it with a magic square and it still returned that it was not a magic square

Comment: I would double check your numbers. Here is my test matrix: `tbl = [[1,14,8,11],[15,4,10,5],[12,7,13,2],[6,9,3,16]]`

Comment: actually never mind something must have being wrong when i ran it at that time because it is working fine. thank you.